# Can Entity Framework assign wrong Identity column value in case of high concurency additions

Tags: entity-framework, concurrency, insert

We have an auto-increment Identity column Id as part of my user object. For a campaign we just did for a client we had up to 600 signups per minute. This is code block doing the addition:

```
using (var ctx = new {{ProjectName}}_Entities())
{
    int userId = ctx.Users.Where(u => u.Email.Equals(request.Email)).Select(u => u.Id).SingleOrDefault();
    if (userId == 0)
    {
        var user = new User() { /* Initializing user properties here */ };
        ctx.Users.Add(user);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        userId = user.Id;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then we use the `userId` to insert data into another table. What happened during high load is that there were multiple rows with same `userId` even though there shouldn't be. It seems like the above code returned the same Identity (int) number for multiple inserts.

I read through a few blog/forum posts saying that there might be an issue with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` which Entity Framework uses to return the auto-increment value after insert.

They say a possible workaround would be writing insert procedure for User with `INSERT ... OUTPUT INSERTED.Id` which I'm familiar with.

Anybody else experienced this issue? Any suggestion on how this should be handled with Entity Framework?

**UPDATE 1:**

After further analyzing data I'm almost 100% positive this is the problem. Identity column had skipped auto-increment values 48 times total `2727, (2728 missing), 2729,...` and exactly 48 duplicates we have in the other table.

It seems like EF returned random Identity value for each row it wasn't able to insert for some reason.

Anybody have any idea what could possible be going on here?

**UPDATE 2:**

Possibly important info I didn't mention is that this happened on Azure Website with Azure SQL. We had 4 instances running at the time it happened.

**UPDATE 3:**

Stored Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_ClaimCoupon]
    @CampaignId int,
    @UserId int,
    @Flow tinyint
AS

DECLARE @myCoupons TABLE
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL,
    [Code] CHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
    [ExpiresAt] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [ClaimedBefore] BIT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @myCoupons
SELECT TOP(1) c.Id, c.Code, c.ExpiresAt, 1
FROM Coupons c
WHERE c.CampaignId = @CampaignId AND c.UserId = @UserId

DECLARE @couponCount int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @myCoupons)
IF @couponCount > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM @myCoupons
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(1) Coupons
    SET UserId = @UserId, IsClaimed = 1, ClaimedAt = GETUTCDATE(), Flow = @Flow
    OUTPUT DELETED.Id, DELETED.Code, DELETED.ExpiresAt, CAST(0 AS BIT) as [ClaimedBefore]
    WHERE CampaignId = @CampaignId AND IsClaimed = 0
END

RETURN 0
```

Called like this from the same EF context:

```
var coupon = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<CouponViewModel>(
    "EXEC p_ClaimCoupon @CampaignId, @UserId, @Flow",
    new SqlParameter("CampaignId", {{CampaignId}}),
    new SqlParameter("UserId", {{userId}}),
    new SqlParameter("Flow", {{Flow}})).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: An identity might be skipped if the transaction to insert a row has been rolled back, or the row is deleted. You call SaveChanges then use the ID elsewhere. Can you show the initializing code and where the userId is used?

Comment: @Colin Please see updated code block. It is standard `using` block for initializing context. The `userId` is then passed as a parameter to a stored procedure which uses `UPDATE ... OUTPUT`. But I assume the procedure isn't problem because the same number of missing auto-increments is a too much of a coincidence.

Comment: I'd still like to see where `userId` is instantiated in comparison to the subsequent update. Is it in a loop and/or inside the same context?

Comment: @Colin See update 3. p.s. Did you get the notification after I update question or I need to notify you by tagging you in the comment?

Comment: Ok. We have established it's in the same context. But I'm with @tne in thinking that this is somewhere in the application and `userId` is being set from a previous iteration. Can you show us where it is instantiated? Your challenge is to convince us it's not :-). And I think you need to tag me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. For one, that would be an egregious bug in EF. You are not the first one to put 600 inserts/second on it. Also, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is explicitly safe and is the recommended practice.

These statements go for the case that you are using a SQL Server `IDENTITY` column as ID.

Comment: Please see update. There is something going on with this block of code but I'm not sure what and why. Do you know what can cause skipping of auto-increment values? If I find that out I might be able to reproduce the issue with load tests.

Comment: IDENTITY values are not contiguous. This is normal. A failed insert for example causes an ID to be thrown away. If it was any other way then only one transaction could insert into the table at a time, which is clearly unworkable.

Comment: You have mentioned that you are using raw SQL somewhere in a procedure. Please show that. The bug is not with EF, it is with your code.

Comment: See update 3 for stored procedure which is called within the same EF context.

Comment: This is getting too complex for me to fully comprehend. I recommend one thing though: put all of this inside of a transaction (TransactionScope) to make it atomic and have more isolation and consistency. This might just be an ordinary race condition. Either between different users, or the same user has double-clicked the button/link that lead to this code being executed. This might cause the sproc to be run twice at the same time with the same userid. Could that be the case? If you set the isolation level to serializable, this will no longer happen (you might see deadlocks, though).

Comment: The deadlocks typically come in places where you previously had silent data corruption. Errors are probably better than corruption. Again, I think this is a race condition.

Comment: If it was that we had only two claims per `userId` I would suspect the same. But the problem is that at the peak load, we had up to 6 codes assigned to single `userId` in less then a sec.

Comment: Can you create a unique index so that no more than one coupon can be assigned per userid. That would help with debugging because the app crashed at the very moment the bug is happening. Or, add a check inside of the sproc to validate that no coupon is yet assigned. What I'm saying is, start instrumenting your app to make debugging easier. I think we are done just reading the code. You keep saying "no this can't be it" and maybe you are right. Maybe not. Start actually testing stuff. In any case I recommend you make the transaction change. Also, watch in SQL Profiler what statements EF executes

Comment: I'm not trying to say this can't be it. But it just doesn't make any sense. I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with even higher load test, not during the test phase not now in local dev. env. But yet is somehow happened on Azure. I am trying all that I can think of and will let you know if I come across something interesting.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the issue with load tests. The problem was in SP. I had race condition between checking if user has claimed coupon and the actual claiming. Thanks.

Comment: @JovicaZaric so how did you actually fix that in the end?

Comment: @Colin Used lesson 4 from this blog post http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_nielsen/archive/2007/12/12/10-lessons-from-35k-tps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I admit I don't know how Azure SQL Database synchronizes the generation of unique, sequential IDs, but intuitively it must be costly, especially at your rates.

If non-sequential IDs are an option, you might want to consider generating UUIDs at the application level.  I know this doesn't answer your direct question, but it would improve performance (unverified) and bypass your problem.

**Update:** Scratch that, Azure SQL Database isn't distributed, it's simply [replicated from a single primary node](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/07/30/fault-tolerance-in-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx).  So, no real performance gain to expect from alternatives to `IDENTITY` keys, and supposedly the number of instances is not significant to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. GUIDs should be a solution to the problem, no matter of performance. But I would assume that just replacing EF insert with stored procedure should work too. The problem is that I still don't know what is the problem. :) And because of that, it is hard to find solution.

Comment: It might help if you can still reference the sources you mentioned (blogs, forums) which talked about the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` behavior you're suspecting to be cause of your problem.  All I can find is this [old bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811/scope-identity-sometimes-returns-incorrect-value) which is fixed.

Comment: That is the main one. Others are just mostly saying that `@@IDENTITY` should not be used. But since it is EF, I trust the guys at MS did this right. I'm creating stress test right now trying to reproduce the issue. Will post results.

Comment: Wait, I missed something.  You mention that the duplicate rows appear in the second table for each row that was skipped because of unrelated failures.  Have you double-checked your code to make sure that it gracefully handles these failures?  If it doesn't and goes on to insert a record in the second table anyway, and for some reason your `userId` variable still contains the value from the previous iteration, you might have a bug at the application level.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be here:

```
UPDATE TOP(1) Coupons
SET UserId = @UserId, IsClaimed = 1, ClaimedAt = GETUTCDATE(), Flow = @Flow
OUTPUT DELETED.Id, DELETED.Code, DELETED.ExpiresAt, CAST(0 AS BIT) as [ClaimedBefore]
WHERE CampaignId = @CampaignId AND IsClaimed = 0
```

This will update the UserId  of first record it finds in the campaign that hasn't been claimed. It doesn't look robust to me in the event that inserting a user failed. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Well the thing is if the user insert failed... How come the procedure was called with a random userId? If insert failed code should throw an exception and stop the execution. Procedure shouldn't be called at all.

Comment: OK. I can see you'd expect an exception and that would stop the execution. But are you sure that sql is robust? It is updating the UserId. It does have TOP(1) without an ORDER BY so it could be the source of updates that appear "random"

Comment: Well `UPDATE ... OUTPUT ...` should be atomic so it should not happen that two, ten or a hundred concurrent calls update the same row. At least that is what MS docs say.

Comment: I just ran multiple load test calling ~ 25/sec. and I wasn't able to reproduce the issue with the same code. This is in our dev. env. I will setup Azure tests next.

Comment: OK. My bad. I think I understand now. Your SP returns the first coupon code it finds for that user. If it doesn't find one it updates the userID for the first unclaimed code and returns that. So there should never be more than one....unless there are unclaimed codes with userids??.....unfortunately I suspect I'm not qualified to figure this one out